# how to apply the diff.sql into the mysql database from shell script

Tags: mysql, hibernate, shell, ubuntu

I had generated the sql file named as diff.sql by using hibernate SchemaUpdater.
How can i apply this diff.sql file to the my database using shell script.
Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ mysql -u "${username}" -p "${database}" < diff.sql
```